# Data context of binding in a DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to understand xaml `DataGrid`

In this snippet i have a view with a DataContext bound to a `ParticipantsViewModel`. `ParticipantsViewModel` has an `ObservableCollection<ParticipantEntity> ParticipantsObservableCollection` which has getters,setters and implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

this:

```
 <DataGrid
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ParticipantsObservableCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                HeadersVisibility="All">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn
                        Binding="{Binding ParticipantName}"
                        Header="Name"
                        ElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnStyle}"
                       />
```

seems to be ok. ie the intellisense can work out that `ParticipantName` is a property of `ParticipantEntity`.

but when I try to use a `<DataGridTemplateColumn>` the intellisense shows it is bound to the `ParticipantsViewModel`, not the `ParticipantsObservableCollection`

```
  <DataGrid
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ParticipantsObservableCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                HeadersVisibility="All">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <materialDesign:DataGridTextColumn
                        Binding="{Binding ParticipantName}"
                        Header="Name"
                        ElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnStyle}"
                       />
                   
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Address" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
 <!-- address and suburb are members of ParticipantEntity -->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding address}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding suburb}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    
                    
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

There must be something I don't understand here - other examples I saw suggested that this approach would work.

Comment: so your problem is about intellisense, not runtime issue?

Comment: Where do you set the binding context?

Comment: @LeiYang yes. after a sleep i ran it again and it worked! - but the intellisense isn't picking it up using jetbrains rider.

Comment: xaml intellisense is always a mystery for me, i rarely rely on it.